# Changing the HTML Date Calendar Pop-up style

Tags: css, html, datefield

I have a date field created using the following **HTML** code..

```
<input type="date" name="fromDate" id="fromDate">
```

I would like to change the look and feel of the calendar popup (not the textbox
), Can any one tell me is it possible using **CSS**, If yes what are **CSS**  classes I have to override.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format This for the input field but the same goes for the popup itself. Its handled by your browser so you need a custom element or a framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: hey, did you get a solution?