# Is there a way to customize html5 type=date UI using plain css?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I wanted to customize the html5 datepicker, `type=date` , and change the picker color to red, date hover color to red, and arrows which is used to change calendar months to blue. I do not want to use any third party to achieve this, but only plain css. Is there any way to do it?

I could not try out anything much, as not able to figure out the `webkit` properties for the `type=date` field.

Note: It is not similar to [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker) , as what I am specifically is looking for is not to style the field, but the calendar fields, like the dates, calendar arrows, etc.

```css
input[type=date] {
 // style??
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: @Pedram , it does not. As what I am looking is to highlight the dates inside the calendar, not the field. When a date is hovered inside calendar, the hover color should be, say red.

Comment: I think its not possible because there is an unanswered question posted 2 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829241/changing-the-html-date-calendar-pop-up-style

Comment: check the answer on this thread. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker/16106788#16106788**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling the calendar for html5 native datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531587/styling-the-calendar-for-html5-native-datepicker)